# For extract a large subset of a table from MySQL, how does Indexing, order of tables affect speed of query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

Sorry if this is too simple, but thanks in advance for helping. This is for MySQL but might be relevant for other RDMBSs

tblA has 4 columns: colA, colB, colC, mydata, A_id
It has about 10^9 records, with 10^3 distinct values for colA, colB, colC.

tblB has 3 columns: colA, colB, B_id
It has about 10^4 records.

I want all the records from tblA (except the A_id) that have a match in tblB. In other words, I want to use tblB to describe the subset that I want to extract and then extract those records from tblA. Namely:

```
SELECT a.colA, a.colB, a.colC, a.mydata 
FROM tblA as a
INNER JOIN tblB as b
ON 
  a.colA=b.colA
  a.colB=b.colB
;
```

It's taking a really long time (more than an hour) on a newish computer (4GB, Core2Quad, ubuntu), and I just want to check my understanding of the following optimization steps.

** Suppose this is the only query I will ever run on these tables. So ignore the need to run other queries.

Now my questions:

1. What indexes should I create to optimize this query?
   I think I just need a multiple index on (colA, colB) for both tables.
   I don't think I need separate indexes for colA and colB.
   Another stack overflow article (that I can't find) mentioned that when adding new indexes, it is slower when there are existing indexes, so that might be a reason to use the multiple index.
2. Is INNER JOIN correct? I just want results where a match is found.
3. Is it faster if I join (tblA to tblB) or the other way around, (tblB to tblA)?
   This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256985/speeding-up-inner-joins-between-a-large-table-and-a-small-table) says that the optimizer should take care of that.
4. Does the order of the part after ON matter? 
   This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340139/execution-order-of-conditions-in-sql-where-clause) say that the optimizer also takes care of the execution order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What indexes should I create to optimize this query?

Indexes can help, even if the columns are only referenced in the SELECT clause.  So I could create a covering index on `TABLE_A`, with columns in the following order:

1. colA
2. colB
3. colC
4. mydata

For `TABLE_B`:

1. colA
2. colB

Order is important, because indexes are processed from left to right to satisfy the criteria for the index to be used.  IE: colC wouldn't trigger the index without colA and colB being in the query, and colB wouldn't trigger index use without a reference to colA, and so on...  But colC doesn't need to be referenced to trigger the index use either.

> 2) Is INNER JOIN correct? I just want results where a match is found.

Yes, that is correct for your requirements.

> 3) Is it faster if I join (tblA to tblB) or the other way around, (tblB to tblA)?

Test and compare.

> 4) Does the order of the part after ON matter?

No, it doesn't matter.